# MySql reading parameter name as column during insert

Tags: c#, mysql

This should be really simple. Basically I'm just inserting data into the table:

```
string sql = "insert into Files(filename, filedate, filedata, filesize) values(xname, xdate, xdata, xsize);select last_insert_id() as lastid from Files";
```

The values specified here (`xname`, `xdate`, etc) are just parameters and I'm setting their values before executing the query.

Unfortunately, something's gone wrong and I'm getting the following error:

> Unknown column 'xname' in 'field list'

I can understand that for some or other reason, it's looking for a column named "xname" which, obviously doesn't exist. What I can't understand is why it's doing this.

Typically I "tag" parameters with the @ symbol (@name, @date, etc) which generally works, but I'm working on a system written by another developer in the company and I have to maintain conventions.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: what happens when you remove filename and corresponding xname ? does it still give  you error?

Comment: @AshReva I get the same error, now referencing xdate as the field that isn't in the field list.

Comment: did you tried as mentioned by SteveP? Also can you tell what values you get in variable xname, xdate?

Comment: I wasn't going to risk sql injection so I set up a stored procedure to handle it. Seems to work fine now

Answer (score 0):

If xname, xdate, xdata and xsize are variables, then you could do something like:

```
string sql = "insert into Files(filename, filedate, filedata, filesize) values(" +
     xname + ", " + xdate + ", " +
     xdata + ", " + xsize +
     ");select last_insert_id() as lastid from Files";
```

Comment: That's a good point. You haven't really given us much context as to how this code is used. You can protect yourself by sanitizing the variables, or better still, convert to using a stored procedure.